# Accessing ipod library tracks in iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

Is it possible to access files in the ipod library and save them locally in my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the ipod library and play the music on your iPhone, that's it as far as i know.
What you can do is create your own playlist inside your App.

Hope that helps.